# Rails : How to Arrange the models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some trouble arranging my models in an efficient way. Thing of these models :

```
City
Building
CityBuilding
WoodProduction
```

Now, of course, a city has many buildings through city_buildings. A city building has some basic attributes like the population living there. However, there are 2 buildings that need to hold more information, like the amount of wood produced, if we are talking about a sawmill.

So, in this example, the sawmill, i would want to be able to do something like :

```
current_city.wood_production.amount
```

And get the amount of wood, provided that a city has one wood_production association. Everything fine till this point.

But, wood_production also needs to store a rate at which the wood is produced. This rate is produced by a formula, that needs information about the level of the sawmill building (found in city_buildings).

I have made it work by using a nested association in wood_production like :

```
has_many :city_buildings, :through => :city
```

So, now i can execute something like :

```
c = City.first
w = c.wood_production
w.city_buildings.where(:building_id => ...).level
```

Which although it works, if feels very unnatural and i'm kinda convinced that there is a much better way of achieving this.

Anything to suggest please :) ?

EDIT : I feel that scope may be a part of a nice solution, like specifying a scope for the sawmill building, maybe someone has thought of something in more detail, i'm kinda processing that idea now.

Comment: I'm being literal here, but surely a building can only belong to one city...

Comment: Oh no, a building is the static representation of a building, so it can belong to many cities. A city_building, on the other hand, can indeed only belong to a particular city  (it's a has many through)

Comment: And what is the issue here? Are you looking for a easier way to get to the sawmill builing from wood_production ?

Comment: to get to the city_building information, please read the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right so you have the through association correct. If the `building_id` of the sawmill is fixed then you can add another association

```
has_many :sawmills, :through => :city, :source => :city_buildings, :conditions => {:building_id => SAWMILL_BUILDING_ID}

w.sawmills.first.level
```

edit: has_one :through to a has_many would not work